Volosoft (ABP): ng-bootstrap
I am trying to use ng-bootstrap with ABP (Volosoft):
https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/accordion/overview
It compiles without errors, but it will be displayed like a normal button:

My question is (as I first thought), volosoft includes originally ng-Bootstrap?
Is it the solution just to manually install npm install @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap ?
